# Angular unit test of primeNg ConfirmationService

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, primeng

I cannot figure out how to test accept and reject functions inside this function:

```
confirmReplan(event: any) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      target: event.target,
      key: 'replan',
      message: 'lorem',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      accept: () => {
        this.messageService.add(/** **/);
        this.replanRequest();
        this.displayReplan = false;
      },
      reject: (type: any) => {
        this.rejectMessage(type);
      }
    });
  }
```

Looking at similiar questions i tried many solutions. One that seems to work for others is of this style:

```
let component: RequestsTableComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<RequestsTableComponent>;
let confirmationServiceSpy: ConfirmationService;
let requestServiceSpy: RequestApiService;
let messageServiceSpy: MessageService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [RequestsTableComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [MessageService, RequestApiService, ConfirmationService]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RequestsTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    messageServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(MessageService);
    requestServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(RequestApiService);
    confirmationServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(ConfirmationService);
  });

  it('/**/', async() => {
    spyOn(confirmationServiceSpy, 'confirm').and.callFake((confirmation: any) => {return confirmation.accept()});

    component.confirmReplan({ target: undefined });
    expect(confirmationServiceSpy.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

but the spy is never called.

[Code coverage report from jasmine coverage reporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga4bh.jpg)

Comment: Is this just a minimal reproduction or the actual implementation? Because that test seem to bring minimal value. That said - how did you create you `confirmationServiceSpy` ? I think showing the TestBed setup is valuable information in trying to help

Comment: This is all actual implementation. It's minimal because i can't find a way to "enter" the accept() function

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a handle on the argument and call the `accept` and `reject` manually.

```
it('/**/', async() => {
    // associate this spy to a variable so we have a handle on it later
    const confirmSpy = spyOn(confirmationServiceSpy, 'confirm');

    component.confirmReplan({ target: undefined });
    // get a handle on the most recent argument to this spy
    const arg = confirmSpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
    // call accept
    arg.accept();
    // call reject if you like
    arg.reject();
    expect(component.displayReplan).toBeFalse();
    // now they should be covered
  });
```

Comment: tysm, i think it's in the right direction but it seems that the `confirmSpy.calls` is empty. Most likely the spy doesn't see the service correctly or the `confirm()` call and `arg` remains undefined..